# SharePoint 2016 Form designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-form

We have to create numerous forms in sharepoint 2016 (On Premise) for users to submit various request types.
What are the best designer tool other than Nintex.

No Infopath or SharePoint Designer Customizations. Any form builder similar to Nintex / Plumsail.

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerApps to develop forms.

Here are  some articles for your reference:

https://www.infowisesolutions.com/blog/infopath-alternatives-for-designing-sharepoint-forms

https://directory.collab365.community/office365-sharepoint/top-infopath-forms-replacements-for-sharepoint/